# Use of "a" between adjectives and noun?

Tags: articles

> I am an easygoing, determined and (a?) fun loving person.
>
> I am an easygoing and (a?) determined person.

What if we omit the *a* in the first sentence? Does it become incorrect?

And what if we use it in the second? Is it still alright?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am an easygoing, determined and fun-loving person.
This statement is correct although fun loving is hyphenated.  You can see I've updated it in my solution.

Alternatively

> I am an easygoing, determined and a fun-loving person.

This is also acceptable.  Stating the article puts a little more emphasis on the descriptor fun-loving.

The same for the second sentence.

> I am an easygoing and determined person.

This is correct grammar.  Again here the article is optional and implied if not stated.

> I am an easygoing and a determined person.

This again is correct grammar.  The article again shows a bit more emphasis on the descriptor.

Comment: Such short answers maybe fit for single-word-requests but for others, explanation is needed as to why the presence or absence of something is correct or incorrect, what is the accepted usage, etc. You can post it as a comment if you have nothing to add.

Comment: I'll revise my solution.

Comment: What about "an easygoing, a determined and a fun-loving person", it's still grammatically correct, isn't it?

Comment: Yes, this is still grammatically correct.

Answer (score 2):

Without the articles, both your examples are grammatical and are unproblematic.  Generally, one can coordinate several constituents of the same category to create one constituent of that same category, and your examples both have adjectives made up of coordinated adjectives:

```
[Adj [Adj easy-going] [Adj determined] and [Adj fun loving]]  
[Adj [Adj easy-going] and [Adj determined]]
```

With the determiner, your second example is a grammatical RNR (Right Node Raising) construction:

```
I am [NP [NP [NP an easy-going __] and [NP a determined __]] person]
```

where "person" is the raised node and I've used "__" to show its original position before RNR.

If your first example had three articles,

```
I am an easygoing, a determined and a fun-loving person.
```

it would also be a RNR construction, but with just the two articles, as you give it, I don't see how to parse it.